# daynamicjasper bangla font (unicode) vowel symbol not showing correctly

Tags: java, unicode, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am facing a problem in showing bangla fonts (Nikosh) in daynamicjasper reports. What I have achieved is as follows:

[image]

But I want the following:

[image]

Can anyone help me what am I missing?

My code:

```
StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder(false);
Font font = new Font(11, "Nikosh", "/fonts/Nikosh.ttf", Font.PDF_ENCODING_Identity_H_Unicode_with_horizontal_writing, true);
sb.setFont(font);
```

Everything is working except composite letter and vowel symbols.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the same with JasperReports API?

Comment: @AlexK: Yes, JasperReports API have same results. iReport shows the correct bangla version but when running from application, it shows the problem.

Comment: Are you using font extensions?

Comment: Did you have any Update?@sarwar026. I am facing same issue

Comment: Please anyone help? I am facing same problem.

Comment: @MoinulIslam: Did not found any solution till now.

Comment: @MahbuburRahmanKhan: Did not found any solution till now.

Comment: i post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795748/bangla-unicode-font-broke-for-composite-letter and it yet unsolved